# change positional parameters to named parameters in HQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I am upgrading hiberate to 5 now and need to change all position parameters (removed in 5) to named parameters. 
I have a question for how to use named parameters in "mutiple ? in in-clause".
For example, I have a query

```
select people from users where grade in ( ?, ?, ?, ?.......
```

I do not know the exact numbers of "?" in the HQL query. With the positional parameters, I can simply

```
   int index = 0;
   for(Grade g : GradeList) {
      query.setParameter(index++, g);
    }
```

so "index" can help me dynamically generate the index position in the HQL query. If I want to replace this query with named parameters, how do we usually do it?
Do we do someting like

```
String s = "p";
int index = 0;
for(Grade g : GradeList) {
  String ss = s + index++;
  query.setParameter("ss", g);
}
```

then what should I put into the query for "?".  s1, s2, s3, s4???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `org.hibernate.query.Query` then

```
String queryString = "select people from users where grade IN (:grades)";
// Query query = session.createQuery (queryString);

query.setParameterList("grades", gradeList);
```

If you're using JPA then

```
query.setParameter("grades", gradeList);
```